# Counting Cells in a Sector

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion

Problem Statement - Counting Cells in a Sector

Consider a two-dimensional grid of cells, each of which may be empty or filled. The filled cells  that are connected form a sector. Two cells are said to be connected if they are adjacent to each other horizontally, vertically or diagonally. There may be several sectors on the grid. Your job is to find the largest sector (in terms of number of cells) on the grid.

The grid is given as a 2D array of 0's and 1's, each composed of 0s and 1s. The 1 indicates that the cell is filled and 0 indicates an empty cell.

The following 2D array of illustrates a grid with 3 sectors (the largest contains 5 cells).

- 110000
- 011000
- 001000
- 000001
- 100001
- 010011

Determines the size of the largest sector for a given grid.

```
class Cell {
    int value;
    boolean checked;
    Cell(int value,boolean checked) {
        this.value = value;
        this.checked = checked;
    }
}

public class CountSectorSize {
    int traverseGrid(Cell[][] a) {
        int tempSectorSize, sectorSize = 0;
        // Cell[][] a = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; ++j) {
                if ((a[i][j].value == 0) || (a[i][j].checked == true))
                    continue;
                else {
                    tempSectorSize = findSectorSize(a, i, j);
                    System.out.println (tempSectorSize);
                    if (tempSectorSize > sectorSize)
                        sectorSize = tempSectorSize;
                    ++j;
                }
            }
        return sectorSize;
    }
int findSectorSize(Cell[][] a, int i, int j) {
    if ((i >= 0) && (i < a.length) && (j >= 0) && (j < a[i].length)) { // Check
        // Boundaries check
        if ((a[i][j].value == 0) || (a[i][j].checked == true))
            return 0;
        else {
            a[i][j].checked = true;
            int thisCellScore = 1;
            //Calling adjacent cells on the top, bottom and right of the cell as other cell would have been covered in previous calls.
            int top = findSectorSize(a, i - 1, j);
            int topRight = findSectorSize(a, i - 1, j + 1);
            int after = findSectorSize(a, i, j + 1);
            int bottomRight = findSectorSize(a, i + 1, j + 1);
            int bottom = findSectorSize(a, i + 1, j);
            return thisCellScore+ top + topRight + after + bottomRight
                    + bottom;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CountSectorSize countSectorSize = new CountSectorSize();
    // Sample Grid
    Cell[][] sample = {{new Cell(1,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(1,false),new Cell(1,false)},
            {new Cell(1,false),new Cell(1,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(1,false)},
            {new Cell(0,false),new Cell(1,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(1,false)},
            {new Cell(1,false),new Cell(1,false),new Cell(1,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(1,false)},
            {new Cell(1,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(1,false)},
            {new Cell(1,false),new Cell(1,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(1,false)},
            {new Cell(0,false),new Cell(1,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(1,false)},
            {new Cell(1,false),new Cell(1,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(0,false),new Cell(0,false)}};
    System.out.println("Final Result \t "+countSectorSize.traverseGrid(sample));
    }
}
```

With this sample input in main method,I should get 13 as output. But actual outpu is 8.
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You should get 5 as the output right, as largest connected sector has 5 one's , If you look at the top left section.

Comment: Thanks @zenwraight I refering to sample input in main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is need to recursively call all the adjacent cells as you cann't be sure of the location of the cell where your 
current invocation has taken place from. Try adding

```
            int bottomLeft = findSectorSize(a, i + 1, j - 1);
            int before = findSectorSize(a, i, j - 1);
            int topLeft = findSectorSize(a, i - 1, j - 1);
            return thisCellScore + top + topRight + after + bottomRight
                    + bottom + bottomLeft + before + topLeft;
```